# What is the triple Ethereum Halving happening in 2022?

Tags: blockchain

I read someone where in 2022, Ethereum is going to have a triple halving of its supply. What is this exactly? And is it 100% going to happen or is it just speculation?

Answer (score 0):

Halving creates scarcity which pushes the price of the coin up. The more scarce the coin, the more valuable it becomes (do a Google search for: Bitcoin finite 21 million) Analysts compute that sell pressure will drop by roughly 30% with EIP-1559, meaning there will be a lot less ETH available on markets to buy.

Sources: https://medium.com/metapherse/what-is-triple-halving-of-ethereum-and-what-does-it-matter-4a69af4eecb7

https://blog.coinbase.com/the-technical-benefits-of-eip-1559-c41bb85f5924